# Can you use Outlook Mobile Acces with an iPad2?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, ipad, activesync

I have a Windows SBS 2003 running Exchange 2003.  Out of the box, the Exchange server should allow ActiveSync to work and on an iPad, I should be able to connect using Outlook Mobile Access.  It appears to work but when I try to open the mailbox I get an error message that it could not connect to the server.

Any ideas or direction to try to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is there a problem with using Activesync?

Comment: Are you positive you're trying to use OMA and not trying to use Activesync? Is OMA configured and enabled on the Exchange server?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box Exchange 2003 does not support ActiveSync, you need Exchange 2003 SP2 for that. Also, you might need to activate the Outlook Mobile Access and user-initiated synchronisation (is that correct in english? I only know the german name of the feature) features for the user, they should be activated by default though.